# Automatically Determining a Ruby Method's Raise-able Exceptions

Tags: ruby, exception, code-analysis

Is there an automatic way to determine (or approximate) the exceptions a Ruby method can raise? If so, does such a tool to do this exist?

I realize there's a standard list of exceptions that can occur during the running of a Ruby program pretty much anywhere, but I figure a tool to do this could give you some additional insight modulo that list.

Comment: Not clear your question to me ;)

Comment: Given a method, what exceptions can it throw?  That's the question.

Comment: `yard` does a basic version of this - it looks for `raise` statements in the code. I think that is the limit of it though, and Ruby's introspection is not advanced enough to do much more (variables are not typed, so trying to figure out the likely class of something in code, thus what errors might get thrown, is not really possible).

Comment: Totally.  The dynamic typing of Ruby and all the idiomatic metaprogramming really throw a wrench in the works.  I'm just looking for a tool to get me started in finding some of the `raise` exceptions.  You should make this an official response ;-).